# Split data frame based on if all rows in a group have a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), y = c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0))
```

How can I split the data into two data frames, where for each `x` value, both `y` values are equal to 1?

```
df
   x y
1  0 0
2  0 1
3  1 1 # x = 1: all y = 1
4  1 1 #
5  2 0
6  2 0
7  3 0
8  3 1
9  4 1 # x = 4: all y = 1
10 4 1 #
11 5 0
12 5 0
```

The two resulting data frames would then look like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,4,4), y = c(1,1,1,1))
df1
  x y
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 4 1
4 4 1

df2 <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,2,2,3,3,5,5), y = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0))
df2
  x y
1 0 0
2 0 1
3 2 0
4 2 0
5 3 0
6 3 1
7 5 0
8 5 0
```

Answer (score 7):

in base R:

```
split(df, ~ave(y == 1, x, FUN = all))
$`FALSE`
   x y
1  0 0
2  0 1
5  2 0
6  2 0
7  3 0
8  3 1
11 5 0
12 5 0

$`TRUE`
   x y
3  1 1
4  1 1
9  4 1
10 4 1
```

In tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(s = all(y==1))%>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_split(s, .keep = FALSE)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 8 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0
2     0     1
3     2     0
4     2     0
5     3     0
6     3     1
7     5     0
8     5     0

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     1     1
3     4     1
4     4     1
```

Answer (score 3):

One base R `split` variant.

---

If your `y` column consists of `0` and `1` only, then you can run the code below (thanks @Henrik)

```
> split(df, ~ave(y, x) == 1)
$`FALSE`
   x y
1  0 0
2  0 1
5  2 0
6  2 0
7  3 0
8  3 1
11 5 0
12 5 0

$`TRUE`
   x y
3  1 1
4  1 1
9  4 1
10 4 1
```

otherwise, in general cases of `y`, we can try

```
> split(df, ~ ave(y == 1, x) == 1)
$`FALSE`
   x y
1  0 0
2  0 1
5  2 0
6  2 0
7  3 0
8  3 1
11 5 0
12 5 0

$`TRUE`
   x y
3  1 1
4  1 1
9  4 1
10 4 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(x=c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),y=c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0))

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(all(y == 1)) %>% 
  ungroup

df2 <- df %>% 
  anti_join(df1, by = c("x", "y")) 
  
list(df1, df2 %>% as_tibble)

#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     1     1
#> 3     4     1
#> 4     4     1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     0
#> 2     0     1
#> 3     2     0
#> 4     2     0
#> 5     3     0
#> 6     3     1
#> 7     5     0
#> 8     5     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thus:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- df |> group_by(x) |> mutate(all_y_1 = all(y==1)) 

df1 <- df |> filter(all_y_1) |> select(-all_y_1)
df2 <- df |> filter(! all_y_1) |> select(-all_y_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

setDT(df)[, group := all(y == 1), by = x] %>%
  split(., by = "group", keep.by = FALSE)
```

Output

```
$`FALSE`
   x y
1: 0 0
2: 0 1
3: 2 0
4: 2 0
5: 3 0
6: 3 1
7: 5 0
8: 5 0

$`TRUE`
   x y
1: 1 1
2: 1 1
3: 4 1
4: 4 1
```

Comment: whats the purpose of `ifelse`?? ie already `all(y==1)` is TRUE/FALSE. what you are doing is simply `ifelse(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)`. Anyway still a good answer.